# Tackling missing data in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have encountered this problem in a project that I'm currently doing.

I have a sparse dataframe and I need to calculate the difference between the first and the last observation per row under some conditions:

Conditions:

1. If the row only contains NA's then the difference is 0.
2. If the row contains only 1 observation then the difference is 0.
3. If row elements (>= 2) are non-NA's then their difference is the difference between the first and the last (tail - head).

The dataframe that I have:

```
  S1 S2 S3 S4 S5
1 NA NA NA NA NA
2 NA 3  NA 5  NA
3 1  NA NA NA 5
4 1  NA 2  NA 7
5 2  NA NA NA NA
6 NA NA 3  4  NA
7 NA NA 3 NA  NA
```

The dataframe that I need:

```
  S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 diff
1 NA NA NA NA NA 0
2 NA 3  NA 5  NA 2
3 1  NA NA NA 5  4
4 1  NA 2  NA 7  6
5 2  NA NA NA NA 0
6 NA NA 3  4  NA 1
7 NA NA 3 NA  NA 0
```

What I've written up till now:

```
 last_minus_first <- function(x, y = na.omit(x)) tail(y, 1) - y[1]
```

But it doesn't resolve for the fact if the row contains all NA's.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a defined function with `apply()`. Here the code:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(S1 = c(NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 2L, NA, NA), S2 = c(NA, 
3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), S3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 3L, 3L), 
    S4 = c(NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA), S5 = c(NA, NA, 5L, 7L, 
    NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))
```

Code:

```
#Function
myown <- function(x)
{
  #Check NA
  i <- sum(!is.na(x))
  #Compute
  if(i<=1)
  {
    y <- 0
  } else
  {
    #Detect positions
    j1 <- max(which(!is.na(x)))
    j2 <- min(which(!is.na(x)))
    #Diff
    y <- x[j1]-x[j2]
  }
  return(y)
}
#Apply function by row
df$NewVar <- apply(df,1,myown)
```

Output:

```
  S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 NewVar
1 NA NA NA NA NA      0
2 NA  3 NA  5 NA      2
3  1 NA NA NA  5      4
4  1 NA  2 NA  7      6
5  2 NA NA NA NA      0
6 NA NA  3  4 NA      1
7 NA NA  3 NA NA      0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easier (in my mind) way to handle this, using `rowwise` from the `dplyr` package to do calculations along rows.

```
df %>% 
  dplyr::rowwise() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(max_pop = max(which(!is.na(dplyr::c_across(S1:S5)))),
                min_pop = min(which(!is.na(dplyr::c_across(S1:S5)))),
                diff = tidyr::replace_na(dplyr::c_across()[max_pop] - dplyr::c_across()[min_pop], 0))
```

I've broken that `mutate` call down into the various parts to show what we're doing, but essentially, it goes across all columns in a row to find the last populated column (`max_pop`), the first populated column (`min_pop`) and then uses those values to retrieve the values therein.

You have to specify columns for `max_pop` and `min_pop` above because creating new interim columns affects the column indexing. `c_across()` defaults to using all columns, though, so you can actually do this all in one `mutate` call without specifying any columns.

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(diff = replace_na(c_across()[max(which(!is.na(c_across())))] - c_across()[min(which(!is.na(c_across())))], 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

A vectorized option in `base R` would be to extract the values based on row/column index and then subtract

```
df1$NewVar <- df1[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df1)), max.col(!is.na(df1), 'last'))] - 
            df1[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df1)), max.col(!is.na(df1), 'first'))]
df1$NewVar[is.na(df1$NewVar)] <- 0

df1
#  S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 NewVar
#1 NA NA NA NA NA      0
#2 NA  3 NA  5 NA      2
#3  1 NA NA NA  5      4
#4  1 NA  2 NA  7      6
#5  2 NA NA NA NA      0
#6 NA NA  3  4 NA      1
#7 NA NA  3 NA NA      0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(S1 = c(NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 2L, NA, NA), S2 = c(NA, 
3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), S3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 3L, 3L), 
    S4 = c(NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA), S5 = c(NA, NA, 5L, 7L, 
    NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))
```